# NodeJS , how to send response during Promise .then?

Tags: node.js, promise, response

I have the following code:

```
User.getConfByID(userID)
    .then((item)=>{
        if(item.length == 0){
            res.status(400).json({error:"NO_USER_FOUND"})
        }else{
            if(item[0].token == token){
                if((Math.abs(Date.now() - item[0].conf_iat)) > tokenValid){
                    res.status(401).json({error: "TOKEN_INVALID"})
                }else{
                    return mariaDBTemplates.updateOneRowTemplate("User_confirmation", {confirmed:1}, "user_id", userID)
                }
            }else{
                res.status(401).json({error: "TOKEN_NOT_SAME"})
            }
        }
    })
    .then(()=>{
        res.status(200).json({success: "CONFIRMED"})
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message})
    })
```

You see I have different kinds of error messages with different kinds of status codes. When I run this code, it always gives me this warning:

```
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

I think this is because i don't "break" the Promise after sending a response right?. But how can I solve this? Any suggestions?

Cheerio

Comment: try `return`'ing each of the `res.status(4xx)` calls

Comment: no still the same warning:/

Comment: seems like you are setting `res` twice in the code flow

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with your promise chain. in your first `.then`, you always set the response with `res`, but the next `.then` in the chain tries to set the response again. Note that not returning anything from a promise is the same as `return Promise.resolve(undefined);`.

here's how I would do it:

```
User.getConfByID(userID)
    .then((item) => {
        if(item.length == 0)
            return { statusCode: 400, body: { error: "NO_USER_FOUND" } };
        else {
            if(item[0].token == token) {
                if((Math.abs(Date.now() - item[0].conf_iat)) > tokenValid)
                    return { statusCode: 401, body: { error: "TOKEN_INVALID" } };
                else {
                    //not sure what this returns, but it looks like this is 
                    //what you're trying to return the 200 for
                    mariaDBTemplates.updateOneRowTemplate("User_confirmation", { confirmed: 1 }, "user_id", userID);

                    return { statusCode: 200, body: { success: "CONFIRMED" } };
                }
            } else
                return { statusCode: 401, body: { error: "TOKEN_NOT_SAME" } };
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        res.status(result.statusCode).json(result.body);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    });
```

Also note that returning a value from a promise is the same as returning `Promise.resolve(value);`, and will continue the promise chain.

Comment: works thanks:) What if I would have another .then before the .then((result)). ?

Comment: that would be fine, just make sure that you pass the result through to the next promise: 
.then((result) => { ...; return result; })